# What source code in Dart language can be considered as valid and why?

Tags: dart

This script (source code) can be perfectly executed in the production mode.

```dart
void main() {
  int greeting = "Hello world!";
  print(greeting);
}
```

This is a traditional hello world example that works fine in Dart.

The result is "Hello world!".

This script is self enough because not required other functionality and it works as expected.

Now I have small questions:

1. Can I consider that this script is valid and correct source code in Dart language becuase it works as expected?
2. If this script is valid source code in Dart language then why it cannot be executed in non-production mode?
3. If some code that can be perfectly executed in the production mode but cannot be executed in other mode then which mode in Dart more correct (production mode or other mode)?

P.S.

As a programmer, I am interesting not in theory and practice but I have interest only in answers in my small questions based on real example (even if it are very small).

If my questions are not so correct then I would like to know why?

Because they are directly related to programming in Dart language.

Answer (score 6):

It is valid because types are ignored in production mode.

In checked mode (intended for development only) types are checked and you get an exception.

Types in Dart are not for runtime but for development time to make tools able to reason about the code and show possible bugs.
This means it doesn't matter if you type `String` or `var`. You cannot omit it completely because this violates the syntax.

It can be executed in production mode

```bash
# ~/dart/playground/bin/dart_valid
 $ dart main.dart
Hello world!
```

It fails in checked mode (development mode)

```bash
# ~/dart/playground/bin/dart_valid
 $ dart -c main.dart
Unhandled exception:
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'greeting'.
#0      main (file:///home/zoechi/source/my/dart/playground/bin/dart_valid/main.dart:2:18)
#1      _startIsolate.isolateStartHandler (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:216)
#2      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:115)
```

`pub build` fails because it uses the analyzer which utilizes type annotations like in checked mode and throws.

Comment: If it is valid (as you say) then can I compile it to Javascript? Also you answer just on the first (simplest) question.

Comment: Also you say "Types in Dart are not for runtime but for development time". But the generated javascript source code used in runtime these types and cannot work without them even in production mode. Also Dart VM used types in runtime and cannot operate without them. How should I understand your words?

Comment: Can you build to JavaScript and it fails when you execute it, or does it fail when you execute `pub build`/`dart2js`? I also extended my answer.

Comment: According to the language specification (which are primary) the tools such as pub and analyzer is secondary things. If they used for compilation they must follow language specification. If my sample considered as a valid is must be compiled by the other tools. Given the fact that (as you say) types are not used other than for development.

Comment: >> Can you build to JavaScript. I cannot. It is now very hard in Dart.

Comment: IMHO dart2js (generated JS) is not Dart anymore so this doesn't apply.

Comment: >> IMHO dart2js (generated JS) is not Dart anymore so this doesn't apply. << But input source code in Dart language for these tools still Dart or not? How they perceive this code? If the source code works fine in production mode and it can be considered as a valid (becuase types in Dart not required) then it must be compiled by other tools or not?

Comment: I think this very opinionated and doesn't fit on StackOverflow. For such discussions the Dart Google groups are a better fit.